# (ASM) Trouble Loading a Byte to a register

Tags: assembly, mips

I am trying to load a byte to a register in MIPS. This is a beginner's course, so advanced instructions are not allowed yet. (No loops, etc.)

However, it is loading an incorrect value.

I think this line is incorrect:

```
lb $10,2($8)            # load byte 133
```

It is loading -123 to register $10!?

In this lesson, we have only just learnt about loading/storing bytes. So possible I'm making an error with the offset+base_address. Although, I can't see what my error is.

**Can you help/advise? :)**

```
## sum values, compute average, store result in memory ##
## $7=accumulator   $8=base address     $9=temp     $10=temp
## data segment starts at 0x10000000

.data
.byte 12
.byte 97
.byte 133
.byte 82
.byte 236

.text
main:

lui $8,0x1000       # initialise base address
lb $7,0($8)         # load byte 12
lb $9,1($8)         # load byte 97
ori $10,$0,5        # total amount of integers
lb $10,2($8)        # load byte 133
addu $7,$7,$9       # 12+97
lb $9,3($8)         # load byte 82
addu $7,$7,$10      # add 133 to subtotal
lb $8,4($8)         # load byte 236
addu $7,$7,$9       # add 82 to subtotal
addu $7,$7,$8       # add 236 to subtotal
                ##calculate average##
div $7,$10          # sum / number of items
mflo $10            # average
sb $10,10($8)       # store average in 0x10000010
sll $0,$0,0         # nop for load/store delay
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change:

```
lb $10,2($8)        # load byte 133
```

to:

```
lbu $10,2($8)        # load byte 133
```

The reason for this is that 133 is equal to 0x85 which is a negative value when using signed representation at 8 bits. You therefore need to use the unsigned load byte instruction, `lbu`, in order to avoid sign extension.

Really you should use `lbu` for each of your 5 loads, since all your values are unsigned. You'll see the same problem with the fifth value (236).

Comment: @user2071506: you might want to mark this answer as accepted if this is the solution to the problem.